# How to properly decide on a new site policy?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, policy

[This question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/813/specific-questions) was asked on meta.codereview.SE for deciding on a new site policy. There was not much for a response but all the response agreed on one thing.

Now there seem to be people saying that the OP(a moderator) didn't have the authority to decide on a new site policy like [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30258/which-is-good-coding-style-when-returning-object-in-java#comment48155_30258). I wanted to know how to properly deal with such situations on a new website? There has to be some way to properly decide a new policy. How? More discussion? What if people don't participate on meta? Then what? Start using that policy and redirecting people to te original discussion asking them to post their opinions?

What is the proper way to decide on the site policy without dividing the community? Who can the final arbiter in this case?

Comment: Four days is not a lot of time to open the floor

Comment: @random I had that feeling but then how to do it properly?

Comment: That sort of thing really needs some time to 'air out' a bit. There's probably no hard cut-off; but just some time for those interested to express their opinions.

Comment: *"He has considered my answer official policy based on the votes it has received."* (Jamal) - So, 4 votes is considered community consensus? A large policy change like this should probably get the [meta-tag:featured] tag so that the rest of the community knows it's *actually being discussed* (and maybe give it a better title than "Specific Questions" too).

Comment: If I were the particular moderator, I would not have accepted an answer for quite some time to be honest.

Comment: I understand that a mistake might have been made. That's why I am asking it here and placing a link of this question wherever there seems to be some debate this.

Comment: Okay, I've flagged the relevant question for moderator attention, asking for that moderator to weigh in on the issue.

Comment: @animuson: I've said that *only* because he said he considered it new policy.  Though, I do agree that the 'featured' flag should've been used.  Again, I'm just following him, but I agree that this case is still open.

Comment: @animuson On quite a few beta sites, **4-6** votes is the consensus. Even after featuring posts, people dont always weigh in or vote.

Comment: And to think, people here on Meta SO are all up in arms about *too much* voting! *Too much* airing of opinions. We just can't win. (Unless we ignore the people complaining on Meta SO about vote counts, then we all win.)

Comment: @animuson So can you add an answer with some general guidelines for future reference? This question wasn't meant only for that particular site-policy.

Comment: As of now, my answer has six upvotes.  I'll let that moderator decide when to take the next step.